# Как применить transition только к одному свойству?

Tags: css, transition

При наведении на элемент нужно, чтобы к нему применялся

`transform: translate(-20%, -20%)` без transition

и
`transform: scale(1.5)` с задержкой 0.3s

как-то можно отделить их?

Comment: Вас сложно понять, вы имели в виду, что вам нужно объединить transform-свойство? Если да, то вот `transform: translate(-20%, -20%) scale(1,5);`

Comment: Нет, так нельзя разделить, так как и `translate` и `scale` - это значения одного свойства `transform`, а `transition` взаимодействует именно с разными свойствами, но не с их значениями. Решения два: использовать TRBL, вместо `translate` или создать дополнительный блок-обёртку и выровнять его без `transition`.

Comment: @UModel спасибо

Answer (score 1):

> можно отделить их?

Можно отделить, если вместо transition использовать animation. Только в вашем конкретном примере нужно учитывать, что translate элемента по ховеру может сдвинуть его из-под курсора мыши, и тем самым, действие hover прекратится или зациклится. (Варианты с js не предлагаю.)

```css
.item:hover {
  animation: hover 0.6s forwards;
}

@keyframes hover {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-20%, -20%)
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(-20%, -20%) /* через 0.3s начинается анимация scale */
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-20%, -20%) scale(1.5)
  }
}

.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  transform-origin: top left;
}
```

```html
<div class="item"></div>
```